# What should be the ideal connection timeout in asp.net application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, performance

What should be the ideal connection timeout in asp.net application? Does it prove to be a bottleneck in the performance of a application. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection timeout I like is at around 30s. Also, newer browsers will time out the page in around the same timespan.

Make certain that you do take a few things into consideration though, [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998562.aspx#scalenetchapt10_topic14) for what I mean.

As quoted:

> It is very common for an ASP.NET application to call a Web service. If your application's Web page times out before the call to the Web service times out, this causes an unmanaged resource leak and a `ThreadAbortException`. This is because I/O completion threads and sockets are used to service the calls. As a result of the exception, the socket connection to the Web service is not closed and cannot be reused by other outbound requests to the Web service. The I/O thread continues to process the Web service response.
>
> To avoid these issues, set timeouts appropriately as follows:
>
> - Set your proxy timeout appropriately.
> - Set your ASP.NET timeout greater than your Web service timeout.
> - Abort connections for ASP.NET pages that timeout before a Web services call completes.
> - Consider the `responseDeadlockInterval` attribute.